# Creating an XML file being fed by a file with 2 fields and N lines

Tags: python, bash, awk

Not sure how to go about this, bash, awk, python, other, so advice and/or various solutions welcome. Apologies if this is too broad a question.

This is my sample demo file

```
Title1,Query1 
Title2,Query2 
Title3,Query3 
...
TitleN,QueryN
```

**This is what I want outputfile:** 

Basically I want 1 `<row>...</row>` per line for the demofile above.
So if there is N lines in the demofile then i will have an outputfile of N rows `<row>...</row>` 
And the Title and Query are changed accordingly in each `<row>...</row>`.
So basically iterate through the demofile to get this outputfile.

```
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>
Title1
      </title>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>
Query1 
            </query>
          <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
 ...
   <row>
    <panel>
      <title>
TitleN
      </title>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>
QueryN 
            </query>
          <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
```

my actual demo file looks like this so the solution would have to actually handle the various characters:

```
index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvd) by device,Total packets received (in the last period) - sum(globalStatPktsRcvd)
index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate) by device,Packets received per second† - sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate)
```

**Edit** My demofile below of 2 columns seperated by comma and with double quotes at start and end of each column.

```
"index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvd) by device","Total packets received (in the last period) - sum(globalStatPktsRcvd)"
"index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate) by device","Packets received per second† - sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate)"
```

This is the desired output if I use my actual demo file above, (although it is not that easy on the eye - that is why I used the sample demo file above for example)
There is 2 `<row>...</row>` as there is 2 lines in the actual demo file.
The only changes are inside the title and query tags

```
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>
Total packets received (in the last period) - sum(globalStatPktsRcvd)
      </title>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>
index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvd) by device
            </query>
          <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
 ...
   <row>
    <panel>
      <title>
Packets received per second† - sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate)
      </title>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>
index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate) by device
            </query>
          <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
```

Comment: your output is unclear. Where do `-24h@h` and `charting.chart` come from? The last *actual demo file* is also unclear

Comment: Maybe it could be clearer if you show the desired output for your actual demo file.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Everything in the output file is constant except for "TitleN" and "QueryN" that is everything inside the title and query tag.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I will edit it to show 2 columns with double quotes at the start and end of each column, although my orig does not but it can be easily added

Comment: @jas  I have added this now, I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple I'm just writing the relevant tags, for the rest it's just a matter of printing your fixed text before and after.

```
$ cat a.awk
BEGIN { FS = "\"|(\",\")" }

{
    printf "<title>\n  %s\n</title>\n", $3
    printf "<query>\n  %s\n</query>\n\n", $2
}

$ cat file
"index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvd) by device","Total packets received (in the last period) - sum(globalStatPktsRcvd)"
"index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate) by device","Packets received per second† - sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate)"

$ awk -f a.awk file
<title>
  Total packets received (in the last period) - sum(globalStatPktsRcvd)
</title>
<query>
  index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvd) by device
</query>

<title>
  Packets received per second† - sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate)
</title>
<query>
  index=snmp_stats sourcetype=snmp_collector_log  device=* | timechart span=5m sum(globalStatPktsRcvdRate) by device    
</query>
```

Comment: tks, will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a go at this: 
Could do with a tidy up/improvements...

```
mapfile -t title_array <<<"$(awk -F',' '{print $1}' demofile)"
mapfile -t query_array <<<"$(awk -F',' '{print $2}' demofile)"

count=0;
while read p; do   
echo "$count"; 
echo -e "\n\n"; 

#echo "do title - count:$count"
#echo "${title_array[$count]}"

#echo "do query - count:$count"
#echo "${query_array[$count]}"

### note the double quotes to access the variable
echo '  <row>' >> outputfile
echo '    <panel>' >> outputfile
echo '      <title>' >> outputfile
echo "${title_array[$count]}" >> outputfile
echo '      </title>' >> outputfile
echo '      <chart>' >> outputfile
echo '        <search>' >> outputfile
echo '          <query>' >> outputfile
echo "${query_array[$count]}" >> outputfile
echo '            </query>' >> outputfile
echo '          <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>' >> outputfile
echo '          <latest>now</latest>' >> outputfile
echo '          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>' >> outputfile
echo '        </search>' >> outputfile
echo '        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>' >> outputfile
echo '      </chart>' >> outputfile
echo '    </panel>' >> outputfile
echo '  </row>' >> outputfile

((count++)); 

done <demofile
```

Comment: yay I found it!!